# Spark SQL expand array to multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am storing json messages for each row update from a oracle source in S3.
json structure is as below

```
{
    "tableName": "ORDER",
    "action": "UPDATE",
    "timeStamp": "2016-09-04 20:05:08.000000",
    "uniqueIdentifier": "31200477027942016-09-05 20:05:08.000000",
    "columnList": [{
        "columnName": "ORDER_NO",
        "newValue": "31033045",
        "oldValue": ""
    }, {
        "columnName": "ORDER_TYPE",
        "newValue": "N/B",
        "oldValue": ""
    }]
}
```

I am using spark sql to find the latest record for each key based on max value for unique identifier.
columnList is a array with list of columns for the table .i want to join multiple tables and fetch the records which are latest.
How can i join the columns from the json array of one table with columns from another table. Is there a way to explode the json array to multiple columns . For example above json will have ORDER_NO as one column and ORDER_TYPE as another column. How can i create a data frame with multiple columns based on columnName field 
For eg: new RDD should have the columns (tableName, action, timeStamp, uniqueIdentifier, ORDER_NO, ORDER_NO)
Value of ORDER_NO and ORDER_NO field should be mapped from newValue field in json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found a solution for this by programmatically creating the schema by using the RDD apis

```
  Dataset<Row> dataFrame = spark.read().json(inputPath);
    dataFrame.printSchema();
    JavaRDD<Row> rdd = dataFrame.toJavaRDD();
    SchemaBuilder schemaBuilder = new SchemaBuilder();
    // get the schema column names in appended format
    String columnNames = schemaBuilder.populateColumnSchema(rdd.first(), dataFrame.columns());
```

SchemaBuilder is a custom class created which takes the rdd details and return a delimiter separated column names.
Then using  RowFactory.create call, json values are mapped to the schema.
Doc reference http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema